# Who can I get as companion?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

In the new Dragon Age, who can I recruit as fellow member of my team; also how and where do I recruit each of them ?

Comment: Parts of the answer to this may spoil plot elements, perhaps specify use of the spoiler markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start off with Cassandra, Varric and Solas in your party - a warrior, rogue and mage.
You can then unlock the following, mostly in any order you prefer (mouse-over to view **spoilers**):

a warrior

> Blackwall, who is unlocked through [The Lone Warden](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/The_Lone_Warden%20) quest in The Hinterlands

a warrior

> Iron Bull, who is unlocked through [The Captain of the Chargers](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/The_Captain_of_the_Chargers) quest in The Storm Coast

a mage

> Vivenne, who is unlocked through [The Imperial Enchanter](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/The_Imperial_Enchanter) quest in Val Royeaux

a rogue

> Sera, who is unlocked through [A Friend of Red Jenny](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/A_Friend_of_Red_Jenny) quest in Val Royeaux

a mage

> Dorian, who is unlocked through the story quest [In Hushed Whispers](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/In_Hushed_Whispers) in Redcliffe

a rogue

> Cole, who is unlocked through the quest [The Forgotten Boy](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/The_Forgotten_Boy) in Skyhold

Comment: FYI, the last two can actually happen in the opposite order, depending on whether you choose In Hushed Whispers or Champions of the Just.